# Thermal Protection - NTC + Comparator + Hysteresis

Tags: temperature, comparator

I am looking to implement a temperature protection circuit using an NTC thermistor and a comparator.
Was thinking of using a hysteresis design I found in a [manual by TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu020a/tidu020a.pdf?ts=1648555030533) -
[image]
Do you think that's a good design (of course by changing the VIN with NTC and etc.)? Do you have a better reference design for such a circuit?
If this design is good, what will be the easiest way to calculate the right resistors to be used?